# Markdown editors (preferably free) that use Github's syntax highlighting?

Tags: text-editor, markdown, github

By "Github syntax highlighting" I am referring to this:

[image: Github editing box, showing beautiful syntax highlighting]

Are there any editors whose actual editing box resembles that? Resembles as in uses similar font, colours, spacing, etc ... basically looks/works the same.

Answers detailing addons/methods of making an existing program look like that are also welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should the software run on? What features do you require? What's your budget?

Comment: Thank you! I will edit my question to include all the necessary information.

Comment: Thanks in advance! Please ping me (`@izzy`) when done so I can cleanup the comments then :)

Answer (score 3):

## Brackets

[Brackets](http://www.brackets.io) supports this with very few tweaking.

- Set theme to "Brackets Light" (it's the default theme)
- Create or open a **.md** document
- In the bottom bar you'll see *Markdown* written. Click on the arrow next to it and select ***Markdown (Github)***.
- In dropdown menu *View > Theme* set font to **Consolas**
- And if you want live preview, just go to the extension manager and search for ***Markdown preview***. Once installed click on the icon on the right and here you go.

  And as a little bonus I included a screen of me writing this answer in Brackets :)
  (*my Brackets is in French but obviously you can have it in your language*)

[image: screenshot]